# Getting exception when instantiating AlternatorDBClientV2

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When I am trying to create a new instance of AlternatorDBClientV2 I am getting below exception.

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshaller: method ()V not found
    at com.michelboudreau.alternatorv2.AlternatorDBClientV2.init(AlternatorDBClientV2.java:106)
    at com.michelboudreau.alternatorv2.AlternatorDBClientV2.(AlternatorDBClientV2.java:100)
    at com.michelboudreau.alternatorv2.AlternatorDBClientV2.(AlternatorDBClientV2.java:95)**

I am using 0.12.0 version of alternator.

any idea why this exception is occurring.

Thanks!!

Comment: This question should be an issue on the AlternatorDB github project.

Comment: What is the purpose of using this lib? You can easily run the dynamodb local version if that is what you wanted.

Comment: I am using it as a dynamoDB mock service for unit testing.Using local version of dynamoDB will not solve the purpose of unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this as well.

JsonErrorUnmarshaller is a class internal to Amazon's SDK, and if you take a look in the jar's source, they apparently changed the constructor to take some arguments recently.

That means that the line at https://github.com/mboudreau/Alternator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/michelboudreau/alternatorv2/AlternatorDBClientV2.java#L106 would fail, as it calls `new JsonErrorUnmarshaller()`.

I'm afraid you might need to configure local DynamoDB. Alternator hasn't been updated in 2 years, there's going to be incompatibilities.